# Combobox Highlight Text

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm having a problem with regards on the behavior of ComboBox,the following is the Properties of my comboBox

```
Combo.AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend;
Combo.AutoCompleteSource = ListItems;
```

The the weird behavior is when i type some text in the comboBox, and of course since SuggestAppend was set in the AutoCompleteMode, ComboBox automatically give some hint. It occurs if the item were selected using keyboard(arrowdown).

[image]

but when i alreadly leave the comboBox, The selected items from the comboBox is still highlight.

[image]

as you can see, the Caret is already on the "Department" Field and the "Payee" selected item is still highlight.

Please give some advice on how can i workaround this weird behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, I'd never seen this before but you're absolutely right. Steps to reproduce: 1)Type something in the first to combobox to get an autocomplete option to show up. 2)Without touching anything else, *use the mouse* to click into the next combobox.

Comment: Looks like the problem is still there in 4.5 too

Comment: since i was developing an accounting system (and users don't want to use mouse navigating around the form).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can get around this by manually setting the selection after the control is validated:

```
private void comboBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text != null)
        comboBox1.Select(comboBox1.Text.Length, 0);
}
```

You may want to bake this into a custom class derived from `ComboBox` and use that everywhere in your project.

Comment: it doesn't work on me :( 

private void cb_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isLoadedDetailGrid)
            {
                if ((sender as ComboBox).Text != null)
                    (sender as ComboBox).Select((sender as ComboBox).Text.Length, 0);
            }
        }

Comment: @jersoft Hmm not sure what to say as I tested a few things to come up with this workaround. Not sure what `isLoadedDetailGrid` is and what it is doing here though

Comment: isLoadedDetailGrid - is just a flag.